# Scavenging the town

Tags: die2nite

So the town died in the attack last night. Unfortunate, but I saw it coming. I hightailed it away and camped out in the wilderness, trusting luck rather than my fellow residents. I am now the only person alive. I've been lucky scavenging. I've found plywood to reinforce my hole-in-the-ground shelter and a decaying lump of festering flesh to cover my scent, but what I really need is water. Without it, I'll surely die in less than 3 days, and I just drank my last water ration.

I'm cut off from the devastated town by a few zombies. With luck I can push past them, get back to the town, and hopefully access the precious well. I have never been back to a ravaged town, so I do not know what I will see when I get there.

Can I re-enter an overrun town? Are the buildings still intact? Can I access the well or the bank or citizen's houses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's  the same as before, but without any defenses. All the houses and banks and wells are still there and functional but the defense is always 0.

Comment: Confirmed. Zombies took most of the water and destroyed the gates, but otherwise town seems normal, minus the citizens.